# Draw a polygon on a geotiff then save as image in Python

Tags: python, gps, gis, polygon, geotiff

Been looking everywhere for a Python, not pyQGIS method to do the following.

I have a GeoTIFF image of a chart with latitude and longitudes. I would like to draw a polygon to this chart from a list of latitude and longitudes then save it as an image file.

Here is an example of what the final output should look like.

[image: final result]

Answer (score -2):

What have you already tried for the python code?